# Determine if message received through NSURLConnection is complete?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsdata, nsurlrequest

I'm using NSURLConnection's `connection:didReceiveData:` method to intercept incoming data, sent through the Twitter streaming API. Sometimes I notice that the data, such as the JSON dictionary of a tweet, is incomplete, and will usually be finished in the following call to `didReceiveData:`. I'm fine to wait and then append if the current data is incomplete, but I need a way of determining that. Is there something on the end of NSData that I should be waiting for, to signal its' completion?

And writing this has also made me consider the potential that I could have a set of data partially received, and then before it's complete, perhaps because the connection was temporarily lost or it was cancelled from sending, I receive the start of some new data, complete. Or I could receive some incomplete data for which I don't have the start of it. Is there a way for me to determine whether I should append this data to my previous existing data, whether it's related?

EDIT: In response to the first response.

When using the Twitter Streaming API, with a `timeoutInterval` of -1, `connectionDidFinishLoading:` is never called (nor is `connection:didFailWithError:`). `connection:didReceiveResponse:` is called, as the first delegate method to be called. Logging it gives this:

```
connection did receive response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17402b120> { URL: https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sun, 26 Jul 2015 11:48:50 GMT";
    Server = tsa;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "x-connection-hash" = d2d3baf7a03549b07abcd9410de47ccd;
} }
```

Interestingly, this time this was followed by a log of "friends", which looks something like a longer version of this (most IDs removed, and IDs changed):

```
connection did receive data: {
  "friends" : [
    189565864,
    224868111,
    89670443
    ]
}
```

The "friends" log comes through fairly often. But following that came some incomplete data regarding a tweet. This was the latter part of that data - it was complete up to the end, but didn't include the start of the data. The start of the data was never received before then.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement `connectionDidFinishLoading(_ connection: NSURLConnection)` introduced by [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connectionDidFinishLoading:) to check connection has finished loading successfully. That method is called *after* all data in the stream has been sent.

If any error happens during the transfer of data, [`connection(_:didFailWithError:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:didFailWithError:) is called so that you can wipe out all your received `NSData` object and check the `error` why it failed.

Comment: I edited my post with further information regarding my issue. It seems `connectionDidFinishLoading` is called before I receive any streaming data.